# Getting following error while stopping apache

Tags: php, mysql

```
Stopping XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-3...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...fail.
apachectl returned 1.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
fail.
kill returned 1
```

i am getting the above error while stopping the apache please help me and i am using ubuntu

Comment: Looks like the script is trying to stop the `ProFTPD` service but it is not running.

Comment: how to stop this and what is the sollution?

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same issue. Since you are getting an error stopping Apache and ProFTP only, you need to delete these two files:

/opt/lampp/logs/httpd.pid

and

/opt/lampp/var/proftpd.pid

When you delete the httpd.pid, Apache is automatically killed. And similar happens when you remove the proftpd.pid.

So now you can go ahead and restart the server and new fresh files will be created. :)

Answer (score 2):

Delete the following files:

```
$XAMPP_ROOT/logs/httpd.pid
$XAMPP_ROOT/var/mysql/$(hostname).pid
$XAMPP_ROOT/var/proftpd.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

When runningsudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop I get

Stopping XAMPP for Linux 5.6.30-1…
XAMPP: Stopping Apache…fail.
apachectl returned 1.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL…ok.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD…ok.

And when I open my browser localhost it’s not working

My solution it’s work for me.

run :

sudo rm -f /opt/lampp/logs/httpd.pid

Now restart xampp. You should not face this problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the script is trying to stop the `ProFTPD` service but it is not running. The line:

> kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]

Indicates that a `kill` command was issued with malformed or missing parameters. If you are not using ProFTPD, you can remove all instances of it in the startup and termination scripts.

The script that you are running is not only trying to stop the apache service but rather all the services that are related to XAMPP -

- **X** is the platform - could be windows, linux or mac
- **A**​pache
- **M**​ySql
- **P**​hpMyAdmin
- **P**​hp

Comment: What is the script you are running? What command triggered those errors?

Comment: i am using ubuntu and the command is $ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop

Comment: Great - and are you certain that the services were running before you tried to stop them? You might just be trying to stop a service that wasn't running in the first place...

Comment: ~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stopapache
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...fail.
apachectl returned 1.

Comment: same error with this specific script while stopping only one

Comment: when i was opening localhost,it was not running and i tried to stop them so the above result shows